# Usage of ‘say I’ &c. after a quote

Tags: word-order

I was doing some creative writing and asked a friend to proofread it. They tell me they choked up at this point:

> ‘I don’t know,’ says Scott. ‘I’ll need to think about it.’
>
> ‘Let me know if you’ll come’, reply I, an insistent expression surely covering my face. ‘I hope you can make it.’

My friend claims that this is bad grammar, but I beg to differ. I usually take the post-positive subject after a quote; such has been how I have written all my life. I see ‘says Margaret Peterson’, ‘says she’, and other things as such following quotes in many books and newspapers. Is it truly wrong (or archaic) to say ‘say I’ or phrases related to it?

Edit: I hear ‘So say I’ as a statement, too. On the other hand, I never hear ‘So I say’, except in the case of ‘So, I say to him ...’ Would ‘So I say’ ever be used instead of ‘So say I’?

Comment: Yes. 'Say I' is archaic or deliberately quirky, and 'answer I' or 'reply I' sounds ridiculous. The use of the present tense is an additional style problem. ' "Let me know if you’ll come", I replied...' is standard.  On the other hand, the third person usage with a noun rather than a pronoun is quite idiomatic in a formal register. Thus ' "It's a matter of idiomaticity rather than grammar," says Querk'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Of course, saying the use of present tense is a problem is topic for separate discussion; however, I would like to ask if you think that ‘said I’ is also ridiculous, or if being in the past tense it somehow becomes justified in its use.

Comment: Edwin can be a little prickly, but do not take his comments as a criticism of yourself. He does this to all of us. And, by the way, he is usually right. :-)

Comment: I agree with Edwin's comments. IMHO "I reply" would sound less weird than "Reply I".

Comment: @MarkHubbard No worries here, I’m not hurt. I take his word, and wish to know (after he said what he did about the present tense) whether his position on the post-positive noun stands with regards to past tense.

Comment: @Mark Hubbard I thought all the questions were computer-generated.

Comment: ' "Let me know if you’ll come," replied I' is unacceptable in my opinion. ' "Let me know if you’ll come," replied John' and ' "Let me know if you’ll come,"John replied' are both quite acceptable, though the former is perhaps now sounding a little dated.

Comment: Hahahahaha! The world of EL&U would be so dull if you weren't here, Edwin. I adore you. :-)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth's "deliberately quirky" and "ridiculous" are a little exaggerated. I'd say that this kind of inversion, particularly with present forms, is frequent in oral narrative and is indeed characteristic of that genre. If you're casting this as a spoken tale, you're fine; but in more conventionally 'literary' fiction it's jarring.

Comment: @StoneyB I haven't been able to find a single example of quote-verb / first person nominative pronoun inversion for verbs other than _say_ (eg asked I; enquired we) and I maintain that the descriptors are accurate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Before I head to bed, here is one example of ‘asked I’ being used seemingly as the set style of this writing, as well as things such as ‘continued he’, ‘inquired I’, &c. https://goo.gl/0ZS958

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://writers.stackexchange.com since it's more about style than grammar.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=rvQ0AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA45&dq=%22asks+I%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9uqr0qNfMAhXHQyYKHQSHDBw4ChDoAQhNMAk#v=onepage&q=%22asks%20I%22&f=false)'s one; and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=FR5IAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA86&dq=%22Yes+responded+I%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhiM32q9fMAhXKQiYKHYTCDTYQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Yes%20responded%20I%22&f=false)'s another. First person is itself comparatively rare in this sort of narrative.

Comment: @ChrisSunami, to me the question is clearly asking about "bad grammar", not for feedback on style. (I think the author knows his/her own voice.)  I agree with StoneyB, and with EdwinAshworth: "deliberately quirky" and "you're fine."

Comment: @StoneyB. Yes, you've managed to dredge two up. But where on the quirky ... ridiculous continuum they are I can't decide.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think it's really a genre marker---colloquial narrative. It's closely associated with a 3sg verb regardless of subject, as [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=GgvHwe8A9R4C&pg=PT230&dq=%22cries+he%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV0_PExtfMAhXEYyYKHcRPAeg4ChDoAQg8MAY#v=onepage&q=%22cries%20he%22&f=false), where the narrator tags his own utterances with *cries I*, *says I* and the like.

Comment: re the edit: 'So say I' / 'So say all of us' are idiomatic and must not be used to judge the acceptability of usages lacking the 'So'. // If you really want to sound like Popeye, '...says me' does the trick even better.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The reason I type the way I do is of course not to sound different nor to sound quirky. It sounds broken, in my opinion, to say, ‘“Hello,” Sean said’; ‘“Hello,” said Sean’ has a nicer cadence to it. The reason I have been using things such as *say I* and *asked he* is because it seems even worse to be using something one way – such as *said Sean* – only to change in the next sentence. I am for consistency in style when I write, as best as I can.

Comment: You must choose between consistency and causing people to choke up at non-standard usages.

Answer (score 2):

"So say I" (sometimes rendered as "so says I") is an idiomatic expression, it can't be taken as a general pattern to follow.

In general, when writing dialogue, your goal should never be for all the variations on "he said, she said" to stick out.  They are there to perform a necessary function, but you want them to remain in the background.

Using an awkward construction like "reply I" does nothing but call unwanted attention to itself.